# What am I doing wrong with my code here I'm so lost

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to input my firestore into the form and put all my user data so I can pass information as

> profile.name
>
> profile.email
>
> profile.location
>
> profile.avatar

so what am I doing wrong here to keep on receiving this error?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ekk9.png)

**This is my mock screen**

```
    import Fire from '../utilities/Fire';

            super(props);
            this.state = {
               user: {}
            }

               const user = this.props.uid || Fire.shared.uid

               this.unsubscribe = Fire.shared.firestore
                   .collection("users")
                   .doc(user)
                   .onSnapshot(doc => {
                       this.setState({ user: doc.data() });
                   });

               this.unsubscribe();


           unsubscribe = null;

          const profile = {
            username: this.state.user.name,
            location: this.state.user.location,
            email: this.state.user.email,
            avatar: this.state.user.avatar ? { uri: this.state.user.avatar } : require("../assets/avatar.png"),
            notifications: true,
          };

          export { profile };
```

**This is my Settings Page**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TextInput } from "react-native";

import { Divider, Button, Block, Text, Switch } from "../components";
import { theme, mock } from "../constants";

class Settings extends Component {
  state = {
    notifications: true,
    editing: null,
    profile: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ profile: this.props.profile });
  }

  handleEdit(name, text) {
    const { profile } = this.state;
    profile[name] = text;

    this.setState({ profile });
  }

  toggleEdit(name) {
    const { editing } = this.state;
    this.setState({ editing: !editing ? name : null });
  }

  renderEdit(name) {
    const { profile, editing } = this.state;

    if (editing === name) {
      return (
        <TextInput
          defaultValue={profile[name]}
          onChangeText={text => this.handleEdit([name], text)}
        />
      );
    }

    return <Text bold>{profile[name]}</Text>;
  }

  render() {
    const { profile, editing } = this.state;

    return (
      <Block>
        <Block flex={false} row center space="between" style={styles.header}>
          <Text h1 bold>
            Settings
          </Text>
          <Button>
            <Image source={profile.avatar} style={styles.avatar} />
          </Button>
        </Block>

        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <Block style={styles.inputs}>
            <Block row space="between" margin={[10, 0]} style={styles.inputRow}>
              <Block>
                <Text gray2 style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                  Username
                </Text>
                {this.renderEdit("username")}
              </Block>
              <Text
                medium
                secondary
                onPress={() => this.toggleEdit("username")}
              >
                {editing === "username" ? "Save" : "Edit"}
              </Text>
            </Block>
            <Block row space="between" margin={[10, 0]} style={styles.inputRow}>
              <Block>
                <Text gray2 style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                  Location
                </Text>
                {this.renderEdit("location")}
              </Block>
              <Text
                medium
                secondary
                onPress={() => this.toggleEdit("location")}
              >
                {editing === "location" ? "Save" : "Edit"}
              </Text>
            </Block>
            <Block row space="between" margin={[10, 0]} style={styles.inputRow}>
              <Block>
                <Text gray2 style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                  E-mail
                </Text>
                <Text bold>{profile.email}</Text>
              </Block>
            </Block>
          </Block>

          <Divider margin={[theme.sizes.base, theme.sizes.base * 2]} />
          <Divider />

          <Block style={styles.toggles}>
            <Block
              row
              center
              space="between"
              style={{ marginBottom: theme.sizes.base * 2 }}
            >
              <Text gray2>Notifications</Text>
              <Switch
                value={this.state.notifications}
                onValueChange={value => this.setState({ notifications: value })}
              />
            </Block>
          </Block>
        </ScrollView>
      </Block>
    );
  }
}

Settings.defaultProps = {
  profile: mock.profile
};

export default Settings;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2
  },
  avatar: {
    height: theme.sizes.base * 2.2,
    width: theme.sizes.base * 2.2
  },
  inputs: {
    marginTop: theme.sizes.base * 0.7,
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2
  },
  inputRow: {
    alignItems: "flex-end"
  },
  sliders: {
    marginTop: theme.sizes.base * 0.7,
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2
  },
  thumb: {
    width: theme.sizes.base,
    height: theme.sizes.base,
    borderRadius: theme.sizes.base,
    borderColor: "white",
    borderWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.secondary
  },
  toggles: {
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2
  }
});
```

Tried to add a class function to fix it but now it's not recognized my profile on my const, tried to change the class name to mock and export both mock and profile but not working any tips?

fixed the first error but now I am getting a second error with my setState

Comment: You should learn Javascript. You have code that seems to belong to a class but it's missing the class declaration and constructor.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part headed "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem". The current title does not summarize the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty informative.

You can not have super() sitting *outside* of a class constructor.

Here would be a working example of that:

```
class YourComponentName extends Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props )

    this.state = {
       user: {}
    }
  }
  ...
}

export default YourComponentName
```

More info on super: https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/

While this should resolve the error you're getting, it probably will not resolve your underlying issue. I recommend researching React state machines.

Comment: after doing this my const profile is no longer being used because i added the class of profile. tried this but nothing export {profile, mock}; how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`super(props);` should be used inside `constructor` on the class. So just wrap your super and state in the constructor or remove super completely.